# UNIT: Unsupervised Image-to-image Translation Networks

Tags: python, networking, deep-learning

how can I predict an image using UNIT: Unsupervised Image-to-image Translation Networks(kind of (**GANs**)) trained model in python? I have two checkpoints for each generator and discriminator produced by the trained model?

Comment: What do you mean by "predicting an image"? Given a training set, a GAN learns to generate new data with the same statistics as the training set.

Comment: @AndreaPollini My mean: I have a trained UNIT: Unsupervised Image-to-image Translation Networks (A kind of GANs) model with its two available checkpoints: _"Generator checkpoint.pt"_ and _"Discriminator checkpoint.pt"_. Also I have new images too. How can I use this trained model to give results from these new images. I do not know how can i write its python code? your help would be appreciated.